# NA return of prediction results when estimating in Logitboost algorithm

Tags: r, classification, imbalanced-data

I want to do a multi-class classification with the LogitBoost algorithm in R. But when I checked the results of the predict() function, I noticed that some class predictions were returned as <NA>. When I selected "probe" as the type, it used all of the test data, but when I wanted to create a complexity matrix, I got the error that the data types are the same. When I set "raw", <Na> values are generated. How can I overcome this? It may be because my data set has an unbalanced distribution, but I know that Logitboost can also be used on unbalanced data sets. The code I use is below. Thank you from now.

```
log3 <- train(
  P~.,data = train,
  method = "LogitBoost",
  metric = "Kappa",
  tuneGrid = grid_log,  
)

pred_log3<- predict(log3, test, type="raw")
cm_log3<-confusionMatrix(pred_log3, test$P ,mode = "everything")$table
```

```
pred_log3
  [1] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 [15] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    orta    <NA>    orta    <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 [29] <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    <NA>    kotu    cokkotu <NA>    kotu    kotu    cokkotu <NA>   
 [43] kotu    cokkotu <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu cokkotu orta    <NA>    <NA>    kotu    cokkotu
 [57] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu kotu    cokkotu orta    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu <NA>   
 [71] cokkotu <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu <NA>    kotu    <NA>    kotu    <NA>   
 [85] <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    cokkotu cokkotu cokkotu <NA>    kotu    kotu    kotu    <NA>   
 [99] <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    kotu    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
[113] <NA>    cokkotu kotu    cokkotu kotu    cokkotu <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    cokkotu <NA>    cokkotu <NA>    kotu   
[127] <NA>    kotu
```